# Receiving Multicast Messages on a Multihomed Windows PC

Tags: windows, sockets, udp, multicast, multihomed

I'm developing a diagnostic tool on a PC with several Network Interfaces based on multicast/udp. The user can select a NIC, the application creates sockets, binds them to this NIC and adds them to the specific multicast group.

The sending of multicast messages works fine. However receiving of messages only succeeds if I bind the sockets to a specific NIC of my PC. It almost looks like as there is a 'default' NIC for receiving multicast messages in Windows which is always the first NIC returned by the **GetAdapterInfo** function.

I monitored the network with Wireshark and discovered that the "IGMP Join Group" message isn't sent from the NIC I bound the socket at, but by this 'default' NIC.

If I disable this NIC (or remove the network cable), the next NIC of the list returned by GetAdapterInfo is used for receiving multicast messages.

I was successful to change this 'default' NIC by adding an additional entry to the routing table of my PC, but I don't think this is a good solution of the problem.

The problem also occurs with the code appended below. The join group messages isn't sent via 192.168.52 but via a different NIC.

```
// socket_tst.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

\#include tchar.h
\#include winsock2.h
\#include ws2ipdef.h
\#include IpHlpApi.h
\#include IpTypes.h

\#include stdio.h

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  WSADATA       m_wsaData;
  SOCKET        m_socket;
  sockaddr_in   m_sockAdr;
  UINT16        m_port = 319;
  u_long        m_interfaceAdr = inet_addr("192.168.1.52");
  u_long        m_multicastAdr = inet_addr("224.0.0.107");

  int returnValue = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &m_wsaData);
  if (returnValue != S_OK)
  {
    return returnValue;
  }

  // Create sockets
  if (INVALID_SOCKET == (m_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) )
  {
    return WSAGetLastError();
  }

  int doreuseaddress = TRUE;
  if (setsockopt(m_socket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,(char*) &doreuseaddress,sizeof(doreuseaddress)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    return  WSAGetLastError(); 
  }

  // Configure socket addresses
  memset(&m_sockAdr,0,sizeof(m_sockAdr));
  m_sockAdr.sin_family =        AF_INET;
  m_sockAdr.sin_port =          htons(m_port);   
  m_sockAdr.sin_addr.s_addr =   m_interfaceAdr;

  //bind sockets
  if ( bind( m_socket, (SOCKADDR*) &m_sockAdr, sizeof(m_sockAdr) )  == SOCKET_ERROR )
  {
    return  WSAGetLastError();
  }

  // join multicast
  struct ip_mreq_source imr; 

  memset(&imr,0,sizeof(imr));
  imr.imr_multiaddr.s_addr  = m_multicastAdr; // address of multicastgroup
  imr.imr_sourceaddr.s_addr = 0;              // sourceaddress (not used)
  imr.imr_interface.s_addr  = m_interfaceAdr; // interface address
  /* first join multicast group, then registerer selected interface as 
  * multicast sending interface */
  if( setsockopt( m_socket 
                  ,IPPROTO_IP
                  ,IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP
                  ,(char*) &imr
                  , sizeof(imr)) 
                  == SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    return SOCKET_ERROR;
  }
  else
  {
    if( setsockopt(m_socket 
                  ,IPPROTO_IP
                  ,IP_MULTICAST_IF
                  ,(CHAR*)&imr.imr_interface.s_addr
                  ,sizeof(&imr.imr_interface.s_addr)) 
                  == SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
      return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }
  }

  printf("receiving msgs...\n");
  while(1)
  {
    // get inputbuffer from socket
    int sock_return = SOCKET_ERROR;
    sockaddr_in socketAddress;
    char buffer[1500];

    int addressLength = sizeof(socketAddress);
    sock_return = recvfrom(m_socket, (char*) &buffer, 1500, 0, (SOCKADDR*)&socketAddress, &addressLength );
    if( sock_return == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      int wsa_error = WSAGetLastError();
      return wsa_error;
    } 
    else
    {
      printf("got message!\n");
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks four your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was a simple typo. 
Instead of using the structure **struct ip_mreq_source**, the structure **struct ip_mreq** must be used if using the option IP_MULTICAST_IF. (The other structure is needed for the IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP option)

Using the wrong structure had most probably the result that the setsockeopt function found a zero where the NIC IP address was expected. Zero is also the value of the INADDR_ANY constant, which choose the default NIC of the system. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check/change your routing table.  There will be a route for multicast (224.0.0.0, subnet 240.0.0.0) traffic in there with its appropriate metric:

```
C:\Users\Cetra>netstat -rn

*****

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.80.254    192.168.80.99     20
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
     192.168.80.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.80.99    276
    192.168.80.99  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.80.99    276
   192.168.80.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.80.99    276

        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306 
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.80.99    276

  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.80.99    276

******
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Adding/changing a multicast entry to the routing table is a workarkound that works. But most probably I won't be able to change the routing table of customer PCs.

Comment: I don't regard it as a workaround, it's just how networking works.  Would your customer's PCs be multihomed also?

Comment: As the application is a product, I can't exclude that.
I already thought about changing the routing table by a windows API function... But I'm unsure if that couldn't result to some side effects on the customer PC. So I dropped the thought.

Comment: Well it would not harbour much trust if you changed it automatically.  If you had something in your settings dialogue that listed all the interfaces and had a disclaimer when they changed it, i.e, "this will change the routes for multicast traffic, are you sure? y/n".

Comment: Yes, that would be a better approach :-)
However, I still can hardly believe that there is no way to force a socket to send the Multicast IGMP Join message using a specific NIC. That doesn't make any sense to me.